# How do I set a dynamic variable in the menu links yml file for route_parameters?

Tags: 8

I'd like to create a menu item that has a dynamic variable in it, specifically the user's ID.

This is the content of the *example.routing.yml* file.

```yaml
example.test:
  path: '/user/{user}/example'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::test'
    _title: 'Test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    user: ^[0-9]+
```

This is the content of the *example.links.menu.yml* file.

```yaml
example.testlink:
  title: Test Link
  parent: example.parent
  description: 'Test Link'
  route_name: example.test
  weight: 3
  route_parameters: {user: 5}
```

*5* is the user ID. I'd like to  pull it from the logged-in user.

Is this possible?

Comment: Create a second route that has no user parameter and when accessed redirects to the first route with the current user parameter inserted.

Comment: I would agree with what Eyal said. Specifically you could access the currently logged in user like this. <?php class ExampleController { public function getUserId() { $currentUser = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); // redirect to the other route now that you've got the current user. } }

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to put dynamic variables into a menu.links.yml file. However, you can create a menu links class and set route parameters in there. You need to specify the class in the yaml file.

```
my_dynamic_link:
  route: my_route
  class: Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu
```

You can also include the normal menu link stuff like the menu_name in the yaml file.

The class extends MenuLinkBase and requires the getTitle(), getDescription(), and updateLink() methods, but the method we're interested in is the getRouteParameters() method. Simply return an array with your route parameters and you're golden.

```
public function getRouteParameters() {
  return [
    'user' => $current_user->id(),
  ];
}
```